# Use QGIS 3.2 for TMS such as leaflet 'TMS:true' tag

Tags: qgis, leaflet, tile-map-service, xyz-tiles

Forgive me for using a loose title, I wanted to add a XYZ tile (http://this/is/url/{z}/{x}/{y}.png) with QGIS 3.2 XYZ tiles. Unfortunately, I had some issues showed in the image.

[image]

The TMS layer works queit well with Leaflet.js with 'tms: true'

```
var lyr = L.tileLayer('http://this/is/url/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {tms: true, opacity: 0.8, attribution: ""});
```

You can see [that link](http://story.ceode.ac.cn:1809/image/night_light1/leaflet.html) for more imformation about the TMS Layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a TMS convention tile sets, you need to invert the Y axis, which can be done by a `-y`, therefore `http://this/is/url/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png`.

Comment: Quite concise and efficacious an answer. Thx very much!